# IntentIntegrator class is in zxing-android-embedded-4.1.0-sources.jar but unable to call

Tags: android, zxing

I download zxing-android-embedded 4.1.0 from here: https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/4.1.0/

After add this library to libs directory and `sync`, this library is available:

[image]

as you see in picture IntentIntegrator class is exist but I can't use this code:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
```

I am completely new in Android I really appreciate your help

Note:
I import `import com.google.zxing.integration.*;`
I try to download this library by add dependency to `build.gradle` but gradle can't download it. I tried different repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to download this library directly. Instead of this, you can add a dependency into your `build.gradle` file which is located in your `app` module. I've tried it now and `IntentIntegrator` is available.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0'
}
```

Also, you have to add `jcenter()` into project level `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

More detailed information about library configuration you can find [here](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded).

Comment: I try to download this library by add dependency to `build.gradle` but gradle can't download it. I tried different repositories.

Comment: Thank you @kostyabakay but `gradle` return `ERROR: Connection reset`

Comment: @Masi try to add google() in the same way as jcenter()

Comment: I add `google()` and `mavenCentral()` but `gradle` return: `build.gradle: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0.`

Comment: @Masi try to disable Gradle offline work: go to File->Other Settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option

Comment: @Masi you definitely should fix your Gradle problems at first